# Creating a dictionary by having type of enum and string

Tags: java, dictionary

I am fairly new to Java. What I wanted to do is to have a dictionary which type like this .

My code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution{

public enum Num{
        COMPLETE,
        NOTYET
}

public static final Map<Num,String> Numbering;
static{
        Map<Num,String> putting = new EnumMap<>(Num.class);
        putting.put(Num.COMPLETE, "comp");
        putting.put(Num.NOTYET, "yet");

}
everything = Collections.unmodifiableMaps(putting);

public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(everything);

}
}
```

First I wish to create a class for enum within class Solution(Please tell me If I understand it wrongly, maybe enum is not a class). Then I create a method.... here actually I dont know why I need to use "static" in LINE 13 to store the dictionary.

I wish to finally print the dictionary and check whether is correct or not.

My expected output:
---- Im showing the python dictionary I guess since I used mainly python----

```
COMPLETE:"comp"
NOTYET:"yet"
```

My error when attempt to compile in linux:

```
everything = Collections.unmodifiableMaps(putting); //this line with problem.
```

Comment: why would you want to use an enum for this?

Comment: what is `everything`?

Answer (score 0):

Put `everything = Collections.unmodifiableMaps(putting);` inside static block.

Also you don't have field `everything`. You mean `Numbering`?

Comment: Thanks, I just found out that I make mistakes in my codes. I also posted my correct version

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore my question. Its solved:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
public class Solution{

public enum Num{
        COMPLETE,
        NOTYET,
}

public static final Map<Num,String> Numbering;
static{
        Map<Num,String> putting = new EnumMap<>(Num.class);
        putting.put(Num.COMPLETE, "comp");
        putting.put(Num.NOTYET, "yet");

        Numbering = Collections.unmodifiableMap(putting);

}
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Numbering);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum types in Java can already associate a value to the Enum code. See the "Planet" example from the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).
Not sure about why you want to do with your map later, but this should simplify your code!

You could create something like this:

```
public enum Num {
    COMPLETE("comp"),
    NOTYET  ("notyet");

    private final double value;

    Num(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```